# NOT words in Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to grab the text after the first hyphen in a pattern

`<title>.*?-(.*?)(-|<\/title>)`

which then grabs `DesiredText` from the pattern below:

`<title>Stuff - DesiredText - Other Stuff</title>`

However in this pattern:

`<title>Stuff - Unwanted - DesiredText - Otherstuff</title>`

I want it to skip the 'Unwanted' text and match the text after the next hyphen instead (DesiredText). I made a regex101 with both patterns and need to modify my basic regex so that if a word or words I don't want to match are present in that `capture group` it then matches the second hyphen text instead:

https://regex101.com/r/veSqH3/1

Comment: So what’s the pattern here? Do you need to get the second to last word from the title?

Comment: You want the first substring that is preceded by a `-` but not if it is `Unwanted`?  Is this the correct result: https://regex101.com/r/veSqH3/3 ?  If so, I can post an answer for you.

Comment: Instead of an overly complicated regex pattern, why not do your original pattern, check the contents, if it has your unwanted words, use a second regex pattern match that skips it.  Having your code readable is often better than less lines.

Answer (score 0):

This will use a negative lookahead to disqualify `Note`.  There may be ways to optimize the pattern, but I cannot do so with confidence because I don't know how variable your inputs strings are.

Pattern: `/<title>.*?- (?P<title>(?!Note).*?)(?= -|<])/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/veSqH3/7)

I am using a positive lookahead to ensure the captured match doesn't have any unwanted trailing characters.

---

If you just want the second last delimited value, you could do something like this to return the value as the fullstring match:

```
~- \K[^-]*(?= - [^-]*?</title>)~
```

Or faster with a capture group:

```
~- ([^-]*) - [^-]*?</title>~
```

This assumes there are no hyphens in the value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for. The key is in using the caret (`^`) character within the square-bracket character list (`[]`). Using the caret and brackets together indicate a blacklist. It will only match things that are NOT in the list.

https://regex101.com/r/alAZhj/3

Pattern: `<title>.*?-\s*([^-\s]*)\s*- End<\/title>`

This matches anything in between the middle hyphens that is not a hyphen or space. You can of course modify the pattern to include such characters by using  the following pattern.

Pattern: `<title>.*?-\s*([^-]*)\s*- End<\/title>`

This will match anything in between the middle hyphens that is not a hyphen, so that you can have less restricted text in there.

Comment: The OP doesn't state that the `-` delimited strings can't have `-` in them.  Your answer also does not disqualify `Note`.  See the OP's demo link.

Comment: True, the OP didn't state that the middle string doesn't have hyphens in it. However, why would he/she use a common character as a delimiter if it will be contained in the string? The pattern does in fact exclude "Note" (in the first set of hyphens), did you look at the link?

Comment: Some times programmers are not in control of their input.  If this is being scraped from someone else's site, they may be writing substrings that contain the delimiter because for their purposes it doesn't matter.  You are also assuming that each substring only consists of a string of non-whitespace characters.  This may also be incorrect, we don't know how variable the substrings are.

Comment: True, we aren't always in control of input. There are ways to mitigate that, and i'm sure OP is perfectly capable of it. The second pattern takes includes ALL characters that are not the delimiter. It's in the second part of my answer, I apologize if it's a bit difficult to see. :)

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach and focused on returning the capture prior to the last word, rather than any sort of negation. In this way it's highly generic.

This pattern will match what you want in the capture group:

```
\s-\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s-\s[a-zA-Z]+<\/title>
```

If you are concerned that this only match between title tags, then you can add:

```
<title>.*?\s-\s([a-zA-Z]+)\s-\s[a-zA-Z]+<\/title>
```

[Here's a link to the Test](https://regex101.com/r/EbfYPI/2)

The only limitation to this I see, is that it uses words and whitespace, so if your desired match is "- Some phrase -" then this won't work with it, but that was not indicated in your example.  It's a bit unclear because you used "other stuff" and then "otherstuff".